# What does "clever" mean in the phrase "clever face"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know that clever means intelligent or made in an interesting or effective way, but what does a "clever face" mean?

More context:

> The goblin was about a head shorter than harry. He had a swarthy, clever face, a pointed beard and, Harry noticed, very long fingers and feet.

Comment: See the [last definition 4.b](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clever)

Comment: @user178049 I don't think that is the intended meaning. I think the description is saying that the appearance of the goblin made it look like he was clever (as in intelligent), or perhaps cunning (at least to Harry).

Comment: @SteveES Perhaps, I actually haven't read the excerpt. I just think it might be helpful. Also, I haven't VTC this question :)

Comment: Any other suggestions?